# Incremental backup with stsadm sitecolleciton backup

Tags: sharepoint

I was looking into doing backup with stsadm and I found that with catastrophic backup we can achieve differential and full backup but in catastrophic stsadm backup can we achive this at sitecollection level or webapplication level?

Basically i have a webapplication of which I want to do full and incremental backup any suggestoins ?

Answer (score 1):

With the stsadm backup operation, you can do full or differential backups, not incremental. You select between full and differential using the `-backupmethod` parameter.

If you use the `-url` parameter to the backup operation, the backups are done at a site collection level. If you use the `-item` parameter, you can backup at the content database or web application level.

You'll probably need to do some playing around with the `-showtree` parameter to understand the syntax required for the `-item` parameter. `-showtree` will give you a tree of everything in your server farm, and mark what is going to be backed up if you were to remove the `-showtree` parameter.

See [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441.aspx), especially the "Correction" community content by Mark Vogt at the bottom of the page for details about how to get this setup.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE REPLY.I wanted to do it for the whole webapplication. I tried doing -item http://vsmoss wHere vsmoss is the name of the webapplication> but its showing error item http://<NAME OF THE WEBaPPLICATON> NOT FOUND

Comment: @TPOL: if you run the backup operation with the `-item vsmoss` and `-showtree` - what is selected to backup in the output tree?